Fetch names from truecaller api, using phone numbers
I am using a webapp that requires user to input their phone number.
I want the name to pop up from their Truecaller instead of them writing it manually.
Can this be done via Truecaller api?
I got the truecaller appkey and followed this method but it doesn't work.
https://api.truecaller.com/v1.0/search.json?userKey=APP­KEY&phone=NUMBER
Throws DNS error
